Is it some kind of numerical instability for this convolution product (C language)?
I am trying to program a convolution product function in C language.
I am generating sine waves with the following function:
int generate_sin_wave(signal_t *signal, sin_wave_config_t *wave_config, double x_start, double x_end, size_t n_points)
{
    assert( (signal != NULL) && (wave_config != NULL) );
    assert(x_end > x_start);
    assert(n_points > 1);
    
    if(signal_set_size(signal, n_points) != EXIT_SUCCESS){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    double step = (x_end-x_start)/(n_points-1);
    signal->fs = 1/step;


    double x = x_start;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n_points; i++){
        signal->data[i] = (wave_config->amplitude/2) * sin(2*M_PI * wave_config->frequency * x + wave_config->phase) + wave_config->offset;
        x += step;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}





typedef struct {
    double amplitude;
    double offset;
    double frequency;        // Hz
    double phase;            // radians
} sin_wave_config_t;



typedef struct {
    size_t n_points;            // number of points
    double fs;                  // sampling frequency (Hz)
    double *data;
} signal_t;

My convolution product algorithm is below, it computes input_signal1 * input_signal2 and put the result in output_signal_copy:
size_t p = input_signal_1->n_points;
size_t q = input_signal_2->n_points;
output_signal_copy->n_points = p+q-1;
size_t r, s;
float t;
for(size_t n = 0; n < output_signal_copy->n_points; n++){
    t = 0;
    if(n+1 > q){
        r = n+1-q;
    }
    else{
        r = 0;
    }

    s = __min__(n,p-1);
    for(size_t i = r; i <= s; i++){
        t += input_signal_1->data[i] * input_signal_2->data[n-i];
    }
    output_signal_copy->data[n] = t;
}

The code works well if the input signals do not contain "too much points", and stop working if the number of points become high, see below where I am convoluting the black signal with the red signal, the output being the green signal.
The black input signal is the sum of a 1kHz sine wave and a 25kHz sine wave whose amplitude is half the amplitude of the 1kHz wave.
The red signal is the impulse response of a low-pass filter, it contains 29 points.
If I use 500 points to generate my signals:

If I increase the number of points to 5000:

I was expecting to get better result by increasing the number of points, but as you can see the result gets worse. We can also notice that the black input signal is also impacted by the number of points used to generate it.
I don't really understand what's going on, I don't see anything wrong in my algorithm, the only thing that comes to my mind is that there could be some numerical instability caused by the inherent issue of floating-point numbers which is that they can only represent a subset of the real numbers which leads to some rounding happening.
Does someone see anything wrong in the code that could explain my results ?
Thanks.
EDIT: simplified algorithm, but the issue is still there
signal_set_to_zero(output_signal_copy); // setting all data to 0


size_t p = input_signal_1->n_points;
size_t q = input_signal_2->n_points;
for(size_t i = 0; i < p; i++){

    for(size_t j = 0; j < q; j++){
        output_signal_copy->data[i+j] += input_signal_1->data[i]*input_signal_2->data[j];
    }

}

EDIT 2: I plotted the difference between the output signal (after convolution with the low pass filter) and the input signal. The difference exhibs a periodic pattern. Its amplitude is approximately 7% of the amplitude of the input signal (0.1 vs 1.5). I don't know what it means.


looks like your convolution is plain buggy. Why is it so complicated? I don't see why it needs to be – assuming you did actually allocate output_signal_copy to be p+q-1 samples in size, there's no need for your if/else construct.

@MarcusMüller thank you for your feedback; yes the size has been properly allocated (but it does not appear in the snippet I shared). Why is there no need for the if/else construct ? Without it the code would try to access unexpected memory area (data[n-i] does not exist in the input signal for i = 0 and n = p+q-2 for example)

yes, so structure your loop such that you don't start convolving there. You can adjust both bounds of the for loop!

@MarcusMüller oh I see ! replacing the outer loop, and loop through one of the input signal instead of the output signal, I'll put the changes in the topic

@MarcusMüller ok I replaced the code by a simplified version (please see the edit in the post), but I still get the issue; were you thinking about a different implementation ?

no, this looks pretty sane. Can you really check whether both inputs to your function are as expected? Instead of a sum of sines, you'd typically just test with a simple signal: all zeros, but one 1 somewhere in the middle. You should be getting exactly the filter's impulse response.

after checking, I can confirm that the inputs are as expected. And testing your suggestion returns exactly the filter's impulse response

But that filter impulse response is, visually, a low pass filter with roughly 1/10 of the sampling rate as bandwidth, so convolving with that must suppress the higher-frequency sine

also, after comparing the black input signal with the green output signal in the case where the convolution does not work, it seems that the output is almost exactly the input but just shifted.

@MarcusMüller does it mean that the computation of the filter's impulse response coefficients depend on the sampling frequency of the signals ?Because it has been taken from someone else, I didn't computed it for my specific application. And changing the number of points is equivalent to increasing the sampling frequency, so it may explain why the behavior of my function changes in regard to the number of points used

if they are only shifted, and you don't get the filtering we both expect, then all points to you accessing the wrong memory as impulse response, instead of using what is shown in red in your figures. Man your debugger and / or add printf debugging before the convolution to verify what you're convolving with – it can't be that red impulse response.

I was also thinking in term of memory issue, but I was thinking that in some way the output signal memory was overwritten by the input signal memory. I'll test that and let you know in few minutes

@MarcusMüller ok I made a lot of checks, the memory is fine, the inputs are fine, I don't understand. I've fixed the number of points and changed the step when generating the sine waves, and the behavior changed. So it is not related to the number of points (which confirm that it is not related to the memory), but only on the step. I don't understand what it means.

ok interesting, I plotted the difference between the output signal, after convolution, and the input signal. It has a periodic pattern, I don't know if it means something. The amplitide of the difference is around 7% of the amplitude of the input signal. I added the plot in my post

@MarcusMüller I think that the issue is simply about the filter impulse response: changing the number of points in my program also changes the sampling frequency of my signals so using an impulse response that was designed for another sampling frequency is the same than considering that I didn't changed the sampling frequency of my signals but changed their frequencies, right ? These "new frequencies" are probably below the filter cutoff frequency, explaining why the output is similar to the input. Having checked thoroughly my code it doesn't seem to contain a bug, so I came to this conclusion

the sampling frequency doesn't matter to the math here at all – where does your convolution care about the nominal value of how fast your ADC runs? It doesn't, unless your longer signal contains oscillations of a different period in sample count.

But let's face this: I think we're discussing this in the wrong forum. This is really not a signal processing, but a complex code debugging problem.

Yes the sampling frequency does not matter in the convolution fonction, but it does in the design of the impulse reponse, right ? I think that the issue does in fact come from my function which generates the sine wave. The issue in my function is that the number of points not only impacts the number of samples, but also impacts the normalized frequency of the sine wave. The resulting frequency is not the frequency given in the function parameter, but something else.

so, again, a software bug, not really signal processing :)

In the sine generation function, the real frequency of the sine wave is not wave_config.frequency as expected, but is proportional to the inverse of the number of points given in the parameter.  It explains why the filtering stop working when the number of points is increased, because it lowers the actual frequency of the signal, which goes below the cutoff frequency of the filter. And decreasing too much the number of points results in a null-output, that is also explained by the frequencies of all waves going above the filter cutoff frequency : everything is filtered

Yeah, the software was not "buggy" in the sens that it computed correctly what I asked him to compute, but I asked him to compute the wrong thing... My signal processing knowledge is quite old, I need a good refresh

Thank you very much for your help and your time, I'll clean my post and add the "solution"
